# get proportion of each group's value counts after group_by dplyr R

Tags: r, dplyr

In python pandas I was able to simply do `df.groupby(x,y).value_counts(normalize=True)` to get the proportion of each value in a group. However I've been unable to find a way to do this in R.

I've grouped my df by x and y and have summarized to calculate the frequency,
as such `df %>% group_by(x,y) %>% summarize(count=n())` but I'd like to instead see the proportion of each y for each x.

```
x   y  count
1   A   22      
1   B   65      
1   C   94      
1   D   40      
2   D   34      
2   E   1       
2   F   6       
3   E   4       
3   F   13
```

for example, the new column of proportions should have

```
x   y   proportion
1   A   0.0995475
1   B   0.2941176
1   C   0.4253393
1   D   0.1809955
2   D   0.8292683
2   E   0.024390
2   F   0.1463415
3   E   0.2352941
3   F   0.7647059
```

Comment: I assume the value for `x = 2, y = E` should be `0.024390`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need to group by x to get the results in your example. Assuming the data frame is named `df1`:

```
library(dplyr)
  df1 %>% 
  group_by(x) %>% 
  mutate(proportion = count/sum(count))
```

Comment: shortcut: `df %>% group_by(x) %>% mutate(proportion = prop.table(count))`

Comment: @alistaire Is it that much of a shortcut? if you count the difference in keystrokes, your suggestion is actually longer by 1 digit. Would there be any difference between the 2 approaches in terms of computational efficiency?

Answer (score 1):

In case, we need a `base R` option, this can be done with `ave`

```
transform(df1, proportion = count/ave(count, x, FUN = sum))[-3]
#  x y proportion
#1 1 A 0.09954751
#2 1 B 0.29411765
#3 1 C 0.42533937
#4 1 D 0.18099548
#5 2 D 0.82926829
#6 2 E 0.02439024
#7 2 F 0.14634146
#8 3 E 0.23529412
#9 3 F 0.76470588
```